# SSH disabled by default

Tags: raspbian, ssh, linux, raspbian-jessie, putty

I'm quite new to raspberry and linux so this question might be easy to answer but i'm really clueless... I installed raspbian jessie and wanted to connect via ssh connection and putty. Unfortunately i have read in release notes that "SSH disabled by default; can be enabled by creating a file with name "ssh" in boot partition" How can i create a file with name "ssh" on boot partition? Or maybe there is another way to enable ssh?

PS Unfortunately i don't have access to any monitor with hdmi input right now.

Please help. :)

Comment: SSH can be enabled in raspi-config located in the settings

Comment: This is so stupid... what if your only option is to SSH in the device for the first time???

Answer (score 3):

put the SD card in any computer. A drive will appear (boot). Add the ssh file (without the extension) on the SD drive. Done

Comment: Holy... I can't believe it was that simple. I'm drinking to your's health tonight. Cheers! :D

Answer (score 3):

The boot partition is the first partition on the card, and can be accessed by putting the card in another computer.  Depending on what operating system you are using, it may be the *only* partition you can see, because the others are linux native (ext4) formatted.

However, the boot partition is VFAT.